# Does anyone have an example of events (as a function) for FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, events, fullcalendar

I want to use events (as a function) in my calendar. The example listed refers to myxmlfeed.php and using xml. I have tried adding some xml but I return a js error.
has anybody used FullCalendar in this way?

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

Answer (score 2):

I am using FullCalendar with events as a function on [one of my client's websites](http://www.mamatrains.com/maritime-course-schedule/). The implementation of FullCalendar there is heavily customized, but the code below is what I use to load the calendar JSON data.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            events: function(start, end, callback) {
                $.post("calendar_data.asp", {
                    start: start.getTime() / 1000,
                    end: end.getTime() / 1000,
                    catID: '<% Response.Write(catID) %>'
                }, function(result) { callback(result) }, "json");
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

If you note my call to `$.post()` I am passing a "catID" with the request to calendar_data.asp. This is an implementation detail specific to my code; you will most likely need to customize this to your specific requirements.

**Edit**

I'm not entirely sure if this will work with the most current version of FullCalendar. It has been a while since I implemented my solution and the library has changed somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Nathan and I might actually use some of that but it was the actual xml file that is being called that I was looking for an example of rather than the json array.

I was guessing it might be something like

`<event start="" title="" />`